# How to implement shouldAddStorePayment method in StoreKit 2?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

Promoting In-App Purchases in StoreKit, but I didn't find replacement in StoreKit 2

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                    shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment,
                    for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As asked in Apple Dev Forums, Promoted in-app purchases are not currently supported with StoreKit 2.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/706538?answerId=714432022#714432022